The main loop is not working when I am using multiprocessing in python
I am making a speech recognition program in python where I want that when I say "above", it will continuously run the loop to press the down key until I again don't say above, but now after I included threading to make the speech recognizer run continuously, the whole main loop is not recognizing the res
from speech import *
import queue
import threading
import pyautogui
import keyboard
import time
import sys

def speech_func(res_queue):
    while True:
        res = speech()
        res_queue.put(res)

res_queue = queue.Queue()
prc=threading.Thread(target=speech_func, args=(res_queue,))
prc.start()

flower_active=False

while True:
    res = res_queue.get()
    
    if "above" in res:
        flower_active = not flower_active

    while flower_active:
        keyboard.press_and_release('down')
        time.sleep(0.1)

    if "after" in res:
        pyautogui.moveTo(1010,130)
        pyautogui.click()

    if "before" in res:
        pyautogui.moveTo(890,130)
        pyautogui.click()

    if "music" in res:
        pyautogui.moveTo(1680,130)
        pyautogui.click()
                         
    if "below" in res:
        keyboard.press_and_release('pageup')

    if "ending" in res:
        prc.join()
        sys.exit(0)

If I remove the threading everything works fine except the down arrow which when i say "above" will start running the loop but won't stop even if I say "above" again

You don't give the while flower_active: loop a chance to end.

I made a different threading for that part, but still the main loop didn't work

you are not using multiprocessing.

you should run while-loop with keyboard.press_and_release('down') in separate thread because while flower_active: blocks all code.

or you should use if instead of while in if flower_active and while True will repeat this part of code. But it may need also check if queue is not empty before get data from queue - this way it will not block all loop.

while flower_active: is blocking all code so it can't get next command from queue. It would need to run while flower_active: in separate thread. And it may need other queue to stop loop and exit thread.
You can also try to use if instead of while and then while True will repeat it
while True:

    # ... code ...

    if flower_active:
        keyboard.press_and_release('down')
        time.sleep(0.1)

But there is other problem: res_queue.get() waits for data and it blocks code and it may need to check if not res_queue.empty() before .get()
while True:

    if not res_queue.empty():
        res = res_queue.get()
               
        if "above" in res:
            flower_active = not flower_active

        elif "after" in res:
            pyautogui.moveTo(1010,130)
            pyautogui.click()

        elif "before" in res:
            pyautogui.moveTo(890,130)
            pyautogui.click()

        elif "music" in res:
            pyautogui.moveTo(1680,130)
            pyautogui.click()
                             
        elif "below" in res:
            keyboard.press_and_release('pageup')

        elif "ending" in res:
            prc.join()
            sys.exit(0)
            
    # --- outside of `if not res_queue.empty():`
    
    if flower_active:
        keyboard.press_and_release('down')
        time.sleep(0.1)

I didn't test it.
